# What is the correct way to say this?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

People often say "i'm going on a date" but what about if I just wanna say "I'm in/on a date" which preposition should I use?

Answer (score 2):

It's correct to say "I'm on a date." For example, if someone you know comes up to you: "Sorry, I can't talk right now, I'm on a date."